# Database deployment rollback

Tags: sql-server-2019, recovery, deployment

I am looking for documentation on how this is done in MS SQL. I've done some searches and haven't found how to do this. There is documentation on how to set up HA and DR... But this specific process I can't find and want to validate if this is possible.

I am writing a deployment process document for deploying our applications including MSSQL database. I am not a DBA and I am not writing the process for what happens if a server dies or Disaster recovery that is handles by our infrastructure team. The set up will be given to a qualified DBA. The plan for the database is to have at least a three nodes lets call then node a, b, c in an availability group. When deploying our system changes disable/remove "**Node C**" from the availability group. Then do the database upgrade and App changes. Leave the disabled node untouched. Then when Post Production system test have all passed. Back up the **Node C** node and put it back into the availability group and have it synchronized.

**IF** things went horribly wrong and there was possible data loss or the app is just broken and we must roll back before we put the disabled node back in the cluster. The steps would be to rollback the app changes and set "**Node C**" as the active node and disable **Node A & B** Then we would need manually  recover any new data that was on the **Node A & B**  and put it back on to **Node C**. Then take a backup of **Node A or B** just in case and put rebuild these databases to replicate **Node C**

Questions:

1. Is This possible
2. Is there any available documents I can link to that discusses this